# Attach To Process in 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

We used to have an attach to process macro in VS 2010.  This was incredibly handy.  Now that macros are gone in visual studio 2012, does a plugin exist that can do this for us?  Our macro would attach to the w3.exe process and it was beautiful!

Maybe I need to convert our macro to a plugin?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio - Attach to process shortcut](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6696746/visual-studio-attach-to-process-shortcut)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I use this extension to do what you have described: [AttachTo extension](https://github.com/whut/AttachTo) (Search for AttachTo in the Extensions list in VS)