# How to debug Silverlight embedded in a WebBrowser Control?

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, debugging, browser

I have a WPF application with a WebBrowser Control. The WebBrowser loads a page with a Silverlight application. Is it possible to debug both applications together? How do I have to start the Silverlight application?

**Edit:**
If I start the Silverlight solution, I can debug the code "in the Browser-Window". 
If I start the WPF solution I can debug the WPF Part but I can not debug the Silverlight in the "WPF-Window" - the code works but the breakpoints are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

You can debug both applications - the **WPF WebBrowser** control just needs to be pointed to **localhost** (*via [`Webbrowser.Navigate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser.navigate.aspx)*) so you can easily attach to the **SL app host process** (*IIS, IIS Express, etc.* - *or enable remote debugging support on your web server hosting the XAP*). For WPF, just use <kbd>F5</kbd> to auto-attach it.

Comment: I have edited my text. How can I enable remote debugging with the Visual Studio build in server?

Comment: If you start the debugger in the **WPF Solution** - use the VS Toolbar Menu in the **SL Solution** to [manually attach the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx) to the built in VS server: **Debug->Attach To Process**. See [related SO post on attaching to webdev.webserver process](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7612282/175679).

Comment: Where do I have to attach the debugger of the SL solution? If I attach to WebDev.WebServer40.EXE I could debug the ASP.Net site but not the Silverlight project.

Comment: Try attacking this from the other side. Start debugging the SL Solution, and attach to your WPF application host. I know I've done it - I just don't remember the exact sequence of steps.