# VS macro. Getting the title (not name) of the process to attach to

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I'm modifying one of the [attach to process macro's for VS 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2512935/visual-studio-attach-to-particular-instance-of-the-process-macro).

I often have multiple instances of iisexpress running. I usually run them via batch start command and specify a title - so whenever i use VS's attach to process window i can clearly see the title of the instance i'm attaching to. I'm wondering how do I get the title of the process within the macro. I can get process id which could potentially give me access to title I assume... ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process.MainWindowTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.mainwindowtitle.aspx) property:

```vb
Sub Main()

    For Each process In System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses()
        If process.ProcessName = "cmd" Then
            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", process.ProcessName, process.MainWindowTitle)
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

If you execute this command:

```
start "xyzzy" cmd.exe
```

The test program produces this output:

```
cmd: C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
cmd: xyzzy
```

Answer (score 0):

After you get EnvDTE.Process, e.g. process, you can get the tile like this:

```
 System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessById(process.ProcessID).MainWindowTitle
```